# How to apply a yaml in a Helm pre-delete hook

Tags: hook, kubernetes-helm

I want to apply yaml in a Helm pre-delete hook kind of like here (https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)

I have this yaml that I want to apply in a Helm hook

```
apiVersion: stork.libopenstorage.org/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationBackup
metadata:
  name: my-backup-name # unique name of backup
  namespace: dev
spec:
  backupLocation: s3backup-default
  namespaces:
  - stage-database
  reclaimPolicy: Delete
  selectors:
    cluster-name: mycluster
  preExecRule:
  postExecRule:
```

Is it possible to just apply a Yaml in a hook?  The following is what I have:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
        helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: database-backup-job
        image: "alpine:3.3"
        command: ["/bin/sleep","{{ default "10" .Values.sleepyTime }}"]
```

So instead of a image I want to execute the yaml.  Is that possible?

Update:
I added that yaml and added the annotations with hook but it just doesn't seem to do anything when I do helm delete on the app:

```
apiVersion: stork.libopenstorage.org/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationBackup
metadata:
  name: my-bkup-june-3-2021 # unique name of backup
  namespace: {{ $dbNamespace }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion  | quote }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  backupLocation: s3backup-default
  namespaces:
  - {{ $dbNamespace }}
  reclaimPolicy: Delete
  selectors:
    cluster-name: {{ $dbClusterName }}
  preExecRule:
  postExecRule:
```

Comment: You should be able to apply the `helm.sh/hook` annotation to any Kubernetes object, not just a Job.  But, it might not wait for the custom resource controller do actually act on it.  See [Hooks and the Release Lifecycle](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hooks-and-the-release-lifecycle) in the Helm documentation.

Comment: so I added a annotations with my kind: ApplicationBackup but nothing seems to happen either. I posted the updated yaml.